Laravel 11: "Recently viewed" models fetched using whereIn - how to maintain order?
So I'm implementing "recently viewed" functionality, where I store UUIDs of viewed Products in a cookie:
public function setRecentlyViewedCookie(Product $product): void
{
    $cookieName = self::PRODUCT_RECENTLY_VIEWED_COOKIE_NAME;

    $cookieValue = $this->getRecentlyViewedCookie();

    $cookieValue[now()->timestamp] = $product->getKey();

    $cookieValue = collect($cookieValue)
        ->unique()
        ->sortKeysDesc()
        ->take(self::PRODUCT_RECENTLY_VIEWED_COOKIE_QTY_LIMIT)
        ->toJson();

    $minutes = 60 * 24 * self::PRODUCT_RECENTLY_VIEWED_COOKIE_TTL_DAYS;

    $this->cookieFactory->queue(
        $cookieName,
        $cookieValue,
        $minutes,
    );
}

This works fine.
When I fetch this array from cookie, I do:
public function getRecentlyViewedCookie(): array
{
    $cookieName = self::PRODUCT_RECENTLY_VIEWED_COOKIE_NAME;

    try {
        $cookieValue = request()->cookie($cookieName);
        $cookieValue = json_decode($cookieValue, true);
    } catch (Exception) {
        $cookieValue = [];
    }

    return (array) $cookieValue;
}

and I get:
array:12 [▼ // app/Services/ProductService.php:221
  1733159352 => "9d9e9b2b-0974-4577-b75e-60d647f88bbf"
  1733159348 => "9d9e9b2a-fe8f-44f3-b383-2eaa3614456c"
  1733159341 => "9d9e9b2a-fcf6-419c-9e4b-b7c3f4ec8757"
  1733159331 => "9d9e9b2a-f60f-42e1-9371-f831b1a28593"
  1733159328 => "9d9e9b2a-f422-4faa-baad-16d9a147aaaf"
  1733159326 => "9d9e9b2a-f121-4a46-a85d-8e0021172c52"
  1733159175 => "9d989879-ddfc-48be-a581-f41036133017"
  1733159163 => "9d989878-c8e9-4b75-af30-799ec780cfa7"
  1733159161 => "9d989878-c69f-4833-add1-12b7d0f43c1f"
  1733159157 => "9d989878-c320-4579-b261-e97b15dc5227"
  1733159153 => "9d989878-b9f0-485d-bca3-304b7ef38f83"
  1733159148 => "9d989878-b64c-49b3-92f4-fd8b01e84dcb"
]

So I know the products as well I know the order when I've seen each as I have timestamps. I pass these UUIDs into repository's whereIn(), but I doubt the order is correctly reflected.
Any hints how to order fetches products using these timestamps?

To achieve this, we can use orderByRaw and MySQL's FIELD.
Grab all UUIDs of already correctly sorted array by timestamps:
$productUuids = array_values($cookieValue);

Wrap each UUID in quotes:
$implodedProductUuids = implode(',', array_map(fn($uuid) => "'$uuid'", $productUuids));

Pass to repository:
return $this->productRepository
    ->whereIn('uuid', $productUuids)
    ->orderByRaw('FIELD(uuid, ' . $implodedProductUuids . ')')
    ->get()
    ->take(self::PRODUCT_RECENTLY_VIEWED_PRODUCTS_MIN_QTY);


Wouldn't this order by uuid, and not the timestamp mentioned?
